# ASPX works locally but not on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have built a random name generator in an aspx page that works locally and even connects to the shared database. When I deploy the project to the webserver I get the following when clicking on the link to the aspx webpage:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'clsDatabase' does not exist in the current context
Source Error:
Line 33:         {
Line 34:                 DataSet dsData;
Line 35:                 dsData = clsDatabase.GenerateName();
Line 36:                 if (dsData == null)
Line 37:                 {
```

My clsDatabase.cs file is in the folder on the server and all the CS0103 errors I read does not seem to solve my issue.  I'm using .net framework 4 and confirmed that the same is on the server. Not sure what to include to be more specific with my issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;


namespace YourBikeTeamName
{
    public partial class NameGenerator : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTeamName.Text = "";
        }

        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Generate();
        }

        //************************************************************
        // Procedure: Generate()
        //************************************************************

        private void Generate()
        {
                DataSet dsData;
                dsData = clsDatabase.GenerateName();
                if (dsData == null)
                {
                    lblTeamName.Text = "Error";
                }
                else if (dsData.Tables.Count < 1)
                {
                    lblTeamName.Text = "Error retrieving TeamName"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    lblTeamName.Text = dsData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TeamName"].ToString();
                }
                dsData.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cs file shouldnt be on the server. The dll should be there

Comment: Are you publishing your project to the server?

Comment: I am publishing to the server. The cs file didn't publish originally when deployed and I thought that was my issue so I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

1) you might be missing the namespace reference.  Have you placed `using clsDatabase` ? This may be needed.

It runs locally.  So, there is no code issues with yours but the reference might not have been there.  Try to reload the project from solution explorer. or delete the application in server and publish it again to server from local.  If you are publishing, could you just see wheter clsDatabase file is present?

> If this helped, mark this as answer.  This will help somebody looking
>   for answers with the same problem in future.

Comment: i've tried adding using clsDatabase but get the following: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'clsDatabase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: clsDatabase should be the name of the namespace in clsDatabase.cs.

Comment: clsDatabase is in the namespace. i'm going back to thinking it's a missing assembly in the web.config file.